# How to use different rules for highlighting trailing whitespace inside a gitcommit diff?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight, whitespace, git

In my `~/.vimrc`, I have:

```
highlight TrailingWhitespace ctermbg=blue
autocmd BufReadPost * syn match TrailingWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
```

This highlights trailing spaces, except when I am still typing at the end of the line. (I obtained the regex pattern from the [Vim wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces)).

What I want to do now is to change the trailing whitespace pattern only inside a gitcommit diff. Background:

- When doing `git commit --verbose`, a diff will be shown at the bottom of the git commit template opened in Vim. The syntax file responsible for git commits is `syntax/gitcommit.vim`.
- The first column of a diff is either `+` (i.e. line added), `-` (i.e. line deleted), or   (i.e. no change). If a blank line is added, the diff for that line will show `+`. However, if a blank line is unchanged, the diff for that line will show  . That is the problem. When the diff for an unchanged blank line shows   in the first column, the syntax highlighting scheme above has a defect: it will highlight the   as trailing whitespace.

  [image: diff in gitcommit.vim]

That is why I want to change trailing whitespace detection pattern for gitcommit diffs. I want to ignore the first column. To that end, I created a file `~/.vim/after/syntax/gitcommit.vim`:

```
" HACK: disable the usual highlighting for trailing whitespace by using a regex
" pattern that never matches anything.
syn match TrailingWhitespace /.^/ containedin=gitcommitDiff

" Ignore the first column when finding trailing whitespace.
syn match diffTrailingWhitespace /^..\{-}\zs\s\+$/ containedin=gitcommitDiff
highlight diffTrailingWhitespace ctermbg=cyan
```

At this point, the vim configuration seems to work as intended: trailing whitespace is highlighted, and special rules are used for highlighting trailing whitespace in gitcommit diff. The problem is that this all looks like a hack. I wonder if there is a more straightforward, or less hacky way of achieving the same result. Could you provide a better solution?

Comment: This doesn't help with the git-diff problem, but have you considered using `listchars` and `trail`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The problem with using `listchars` is that I won't be able to use different colors for `nbsp`, `space`, `tab`, and `trail`.

Comment: You can remove a single highlight group with `syn clear TrailingWhitespace` if you want to avoid the "HACK" in your gitcommit.vim.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an acceptable solution.

First, use the solution provided in the [Vim wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces) to highlight trailing whitespace. i.e. add to `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufReadPost,InsertEnter * match TrailingWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
autocmd InsertLeave * match TrailingWhitespace /\s\+$/
highlight TrailingWhitespace ctermbg=blue
```

Then, handle gitcommit using special rules. To do so, override and extend the syntax defined by `syntax/gitcommit.vim`. Add to `~/.vimrc`:

```
function! s:set_gitcommit_trailing_whitespace()
    " Stop the usual highlighting of trailing whitespace.
    highlight TrailingWhitespace NONE

    " gitcommit.vim only contains syntax for the first line of the commit
    " message (i.e. the "commit message summary") and the blank line following
    " the commit message summary. It does not have a syntax for the rest of the
    " commit message (i.e. the "commit message body"), so we need to add a 
    " syntax for it.
    "
    " Step 1: Override gitcommitBlank from gitcommit.vim.
    "         This is necessary for adding a syntax for the commit message body.
    syn match gitcommitBlank "^[^#]*$" contained
        \ nextgroup=mygitcommitBody
        \ skipnl
    " Step 2: Add syntax for the commit message's body.
    syn match mygitcommitBody "^[^#]*$" contained
        \ contains=@Spell
        \ nextgroup=mygitcommitBody
        \ skipempty

    " Highlight trailing whitespace in the commit message (i.e. commit message
    " summary + commit message body).
    syn match commitTrailingWhitespace /\zs\s\+\%#\@<!$/
        \ containedin=gitcommitSummary,mygitcommitBody
    highlight commitTrailingWhitespace ctermbg=blue

    " Highlight trailing whitespace in the diff. Ignores the first column.
    syn match diffTrailingWhitespace /^..\{-}\zs\s\+$/
        \ containedin=gitcommitDiff
    highlight diffTrailingWhitespace ctermbg=cyan
endfunction
autocmd Syntax gitcommit call s:set_gitcommit_trailing_whitespace()
```

Note 1: this solution depends on the syntax defined in `syntax/gitcommit.vim`. I have tested this using the "2019 Aug 29" version of gitcommit.vim that is bundled with Vim 8.1.2269 (the version of Vim I am currently using). In the future, this solution may break if there are changes to the syntax defined in gitcommit.vim. The current upstream for gitcommit.vim is [vim-git](https://github.com/tpope/vim-git/blob/master/syntax/gitcommit.vim).

Note 2: this solution inherits some of the weaknesses of gitcommit.vim. In particular, gitcommit.vim fails to highlight correctly when the user writes comments (i.e. lines starting with `#`) in the commit message area. This solution will similarly fail to highlight trailing whitespace correctly if the user writes comments in the commit message area.

Comment: This seems overly complex and an xyproblem? I believe the real need is to not commit files that have lines with trailing spaces: a .git/ hook can do that. And to easily find files that have them: `grep "  *$" somefiles*` and to remove all of them in vim [or using sed -i] : `:%s/  *$//` (2 spaces in the regexes)